# Collections in golang

Tags: go, collections

I am using golang as my server language (because I like learning new languages).
As opposed to Python or Javascript, I like the fact that go is strongly typed.

I am looking for a design pattern to allow me to create collections for custom objects.
In Java, C#, or C++, I would use generics. In C, I would hack the pre-processor. In golang, I was not able to come up with a solution.

I could always use interface{}, but then I would loose the advantages of strong typing. (Hello python/node.js runtime errors!)

Currently I am just copy-pasting my collections for every new type that I need, but I find myself struggling to maintain the code base, as now have ~10 copies of each collection. So I'm looking for a better design pattern. (Also, every ounce of my being is telling me that this is a bad idea)

I am not looking for a rant on how "there's no generics in go". I'm looking for actual experienced golang devs who have encountered and designed around such issues.

Comment: What type of collections are you using? What's your current use case in Go for doing so (e.g. what methods you need / other use cases).

Comment: One example (of many): I am creating a database lookup class that retrieves entries from an external database (very similar to a "map" ). I would like the methods to be strongly typed instead of using interface{} . I have about 15 of these "maps" , each stores a different kind of entity. Currently, I have resorted to copy-pasting the same class 15 times, and slightly changing the method signatures. (haven't done so much copy-pasting since I coded in assembly language)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, if standard go data types like slices/maps don't have the features you need currently there is not much what can be done.

What would make implementing collections easier, is adding generics to go. As for right now, there is a draft and second version of the tools.
You can find more information [here](https://blog.golang.org/generics-next-step).

https://github.com/ReactiveGo/jig is a tool that for should make your life easier by generating the collections you need.

Comment: To add to your excellent answer. Goland now provides experimental support for type parameters for generic programming. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/how-to-use-type-parameters-for-generic-programming.html.

Comment: Now we have generics https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/generics